# Regex: match everything before FIRST underscore and everything in between AFTER

Tags: regex

I have an expression like

```
test_abc_HelloWorld_there could be more here.
```

1. I'd like a regex that takes the first word **before** the first underscore. So get `"test"`

I tried `[A-Za-z]{1,}_` but that didn't work.

1. Then I'd like to get "abc" or anything in between the **first** 2 underscores.

**2 Separate Regular expressions, not combined**

Any help is very appreciated!

Example:

for 1) the regex would match the word `test`
for 2) the regex would match the word `abc`

so any other match for either case would be wrong. As in, if I were to replace what I matched on then I would get something like this:

for case 1) match "test" and replace "test" with "Goat".

```
'Goat_abc_HelloWorld_there could be more here'
```

I don't want a replace, I just want a match on a word.

Comment: can you brief an example here the true and false example so we can know what you need

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In both case you can use assertions.

```
^[^_]+(?=_)
```

will get you everything up to the first underscore of the line, and

```
(?<=_)[^_]+(?=_)
```

will match whatever string is located between two unserscores.

Comment: Unfortunately the second solution does not work, try it at http://www.regextester.com/

Comment: If used with a decent regex engine, it does work! ;-) 
Regextester is built upon Javascript, which is unable to handle loockbehind assertions. But it still works with Perl, PHP, Python, Java, .net, Ruby... Since you didn't mention the langage you use, I simply assumed that a generic regex would be ok.

Comment: If you want it to work with JS, replace it by:

`yourString.replace(/(_)[^_]+(?=_)/,"$1whatever");`

Answer (score 4):

Step back and consider that maybe you're overengineering the solution here. Ruby has a split method for this, other languages probably have their own equivalents

given something like this "AAPL_annual_i.xls", you could just do this and take advantage of the fact that your data is already structured

```
string_object = "AAPL_annual_i.xls"
ary = string_object.split("_")
#=> ["AAPL", "annual", "i.xls"]
extension = ary.split(".")[1]
#=> ["xls"]
filetype = ary[3].split(".")[0] #etc
```

'doh!

But seriously, I've found that leaning on the split method is not only easier on me, it's easier on my associates who have to read my code and understand what it does.

Comment: There is the famous saying about people who have a programming problem, use regexp to solve it, and then have two problems (somebody fill in who it was who said that originally). Though regexps are somewhat fun exercise to write, reading them is not my idea of fun.

Comment: @hyde sounds like you are saying because reading regex is not fun to read thus it's not an elegant solution. Or maybe you're not...either way I think reading regex is fun since it's more challenging and it makes me think how such little piece of code and characters do what split is doing in a few lines of code. Challenge is what makes life interesting.

Comment: @EKet Well, elegant is subjective. Short is elegant, but short could mean "fits in one line" or "fits on screen". Something you understand at one glance is elegant, but this depends on the reader. Regexps certainly can be elegant, and often they are the best solution, but when some code has one line of hard-to-modify regexp and 20 line comment explaining what it does, instead of 10 lines of non-regexp code, that's not elegant, even if it was fun to write once.

Comment: point is, for viewers, split() and gsub and other stuff like that can often serve as viable substitutes to regexp