# How to use underscore to separate named group in Django URL?

Tags: python, django

I am new to django field and would like to seek help from django masters.

Now my URL has two named groups (product_slug and platform_slug) separated by "/" as below:

```
/search/canon-eos-1d-x-mark-ii/dc-fever
```

Current URL Config:

```
 url(r'^search/(?P<product_slug>[\w\-]+)$', CustomSearchView(),                   name='search_result_detail'),
 url(r'^search/(?P<product_slug>[\w\-]+)/(?P<platform_slug>[\w\-]+)$',      CustomSearchView(), name='search_result_platform'),
```

I would like to use underscore as separator to make the URL short and clean:

```
/search/canon-eos-1d-x-mark-ii_dc-fever
```

Seems it's not easy to use separator other than "/" to separate Named Groups.
Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

It's a regular expression, you can use any characters you like. The only thing is that you need to be more restrictive in your capturing groups, since `\w` also matches underscores.

```
url(r'^search/(?P<product_slug>[0-9a-z-]+)_(?P<platform_slug>[0-9a-z-]+)$'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Daniel. It worked! It's really problem of regexp. It did try it after referring to another post: 
[Regex: match everything before FIRST underscore and everything in between AFTER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985494/regex-match-everything-before-first-underscore-and-everything-in-between-after)

```
url(r'^search/(?P<product_slug>[\w\-]+(?=_))$', CustomSearchView(), name='search_result_detail'),
url(r'^search/(?P<product_slug>[\w\-]+(?=_))_(?P<platform_slug>(?<=_)[\w\-]+)$', CustomSearchView(), name='search_result_platform'),
```

I tested the regexp works well in http://pythex.org/. But sadly, it didn't work in django. Not sure what's the problem.